# WPF Performance: Brushes as resource

Tags: wpf, performance

The Brushes declared as resources in XAML are 'unfrozen' by default. For our application we have used a tool which generates styles for all the common controls. But I found that it is also declaring a lot of Brushes (SolidColor, LinerGradient etc.) in resource dictionary which is used by our application.

Do you think marking them as 'frozen' is a good practice?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,

See the suggestion from Microsoft in the following article:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613565.aspx

A sample from their analysis:

- Frozen SolidColorBrush: 212 Bytes
- Non-frozen SolidColorBrush: 972 Bytes